# Dapper: Can I query two stored procedures into one object

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, dapper

I have this:

```
public class Item1 {
    public string Value1;
    public string Value2;
}


public class Item2: Item1 {
    public string Value3;
}
```

I want to query two stored procedures, one returns Value1 and Value2, and the other returns Value3. I'm doing it but what I get is a Item1 object and an Item2 object.

Is there a way that I can query the two stored procedures and combine the result in a single Item2 object?

Comment: At the moment you would have to do this separately after populating separate objects.

Comment: Could you give more details on how you call the stored procedure and instantiate the objects?

Comment: That's the question, I don't know how to query two stored procedures and get the result in a single object.

Answer (score 0):

Write both the query in same procedure
like
        select value1,value2 from table1
        select value3 from table1

Accept Result in dataset instead of datatable

```
DataSet ds=new DataSet();
Adp.Fill(ds);
    ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Value1"].ToString();
    ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Value2"].ToString();
    ds.Tables[1].Rows[0]["Value3"].ToString();
```